# strip time off date picker and date off time picker swift

Tags: swift, date, uidatepicker, epoch

I have two date pickers in my view.
One has a mode of date and one has a mode of time. On press of another button I want to be able to grab the values of the date picker and the time picker and combine them into one epoch.

So far I have tried to strip the time off the date picker like so:

```
let dFormat = DateFormatter()
dFormat.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
let dateString = dFormat.string(from: datePicker.date)

let dateObj = dFormat.date(from: dateString)
let epochDate = dateObj?.timeIntervalSince1970
print ("date is \(epochDate)")
```

but I still am getting the current time going along with it. I need it to be 00:00 am because I will then add my epoch val from my secon picker to this in order to get the desired combined epoch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the dates from the pickers

  ```
  let date1 = datePicker1.date
  let date2 = datePicker2.date
  ```
- Get `[.year, .month, .day]` components from the *date* picker and `[.hour, .minute, .second]` from the *time* picker

  ```
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date1)
  let timeComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date2)
  ```
- Copy the *time* components to the *date* components and create the combined date

  ```
  dateComponents.hour = timeComponents.hour
  dateComponents.minute = timeComponents.minute
  dateComponents.second = timeComponents.second

  let date3 = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)
  ```